# Que evento de JFrame me permite ejecutar un metodo mientras el JFrame is Open?

Tags: java, jframe, eventos

Estoy buscando implementar un evento de `JFrame` que permita ejecutar un método siempre que el `JFRAME` este activo,

Si existe el método, ¿alguien puede pasarme el nombre y un ejemplo de implementación?

PD: Probé con el evento `windowActivated` pero no funcionó.

Comment: Hola Diego , muéstranos qué intentaste con código.  dado ya se tiene  el Evento para dicha operación.

Comment: Desafortunadamente tu pregunta, aunque incluye algunos detalles, no son suficientes. Por ejemplo, ese evento, ¿se ejecuta de manera asíncrona o después de alguna acción del usuario? Puedes editar tu pregunta [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/58968/edit).

Answer (score 2):

La Clase [WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) es para este fin , escuchar eventos que tiene que ver con la ventana (JFrame en este caso). Estos eventos son :

- Activa  `windowActivated`
- Desactivada  `windowDeactivated`
- Minimizada  `windowDeiconified`
- Maximizada `windowIconified`
- Abierta  `windowOpened`
- Cerrada   `windowClosed`

Su uso es de esta forma :

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.addWindowListener(new EscuchaJFrame());

class EscuchaJFrame implements WindowListener{
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e){
        System.out.println("Ventana Activada ");
        MethodoaEjecutar();
    }

    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){
        System.out.println("Ventada Closed Dispose");
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        System.out.println("Ventana Closing");
    }

    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e){
        System.out.println("Ventana Desactivada");
    }

    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e){
        System.out.println("Windows de Maximizada a Normal");
    }

    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e){
        System.out.println("Windows de Normal a Maximizada");
    }

    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e){
        System.out.println("Windows Abierta");
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu colaboración

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con el metodo isActive(). Ejemplo, si tu clase hereda de JFrame puedes probar asi:

```
if(this.isActive()){
```

`//llamar al metodo que necesito
}`

Comment: Entiendo amigo... pero no me queda claro donde lo debería escribir para que se ejecute siempre que la ventana este abierta

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por su colaboración, depure el programa, reinicie Eclipse y funciono. Mi código quedo así:

```
//Constructor de la clase
public myClass(){

  addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter(){

        public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){
            //code
        }

        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){
            //code
        }

        public void windowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){
            //code
        }
  }

}
```